# IF statements in R - Always nested?

Tags: excel, r, if-statement, nested

I'm just now starting to dive into `IF` statements in `R`.  From what I see from the [CRAN documentation on IF statements](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#if), it looks that all `IF` statements must be `nested`.

Is this true?  If it is, this `IF/THEN` structure is more like `EXCEL` and, I think, not as straight forward as `RUBY` or `Python` `IF/THEN` logic.  Am I not interrupting this correct?

In `EXCEL` (the gui, not `VBA`), you must run a formula like this:

```
#IF Statement 1
=IF(A1<20, A1*1, 
#IF Statement 2
IF(A1<50, A1*2,
#IF Statement 3
IF(A1<100, A1*3, A1*4)
#Closes IF Statement 2
)
#Closes IF Statement 1
)
```

`Nested IF/THEN` are complicated because you have ensure you close the functions properly.

This next part - I'm not 100% sure on, as I am a beginner in both languages, but...  In `Ruby` or `Python`, you can explicitly write an `IF` function in a more structured manner:

```
IF 
ELSE
END
```

This is much simpler and explicit.

Am I missing a proper way to run this in R, or is it that complicated?  Is there a good resource that I have not found yet on IF/THEN/Loop for R?

Thanks

Comment: As a sidenote, for the example you gave, you would be better avoiding `if` statements altogether, and using something like `x * as.numeric(cut(x, c(-Inf, 20, 50, 100, Inf)))`.

Comment: or (rearranging slightly for readability & flexibility) `categ <- cut(x,c(-Inf,20,50,100,Inf)); x <- x*(1:4)[categ]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually two forms of `if-else` flow-control logic available in R.

The `if` statement is, to a first approximation, much like C, C++, or Java's `if`. Just like in those languages, you can chain `if`s in sequence.

```
if(test) {
    statements
}
else if(test2) {
    statements
}
else {
    statements
}
```

R also has the `ifelse` function, which is indeed much like Excel's `=IF`. The rough equivalent of the if-elseif-else above would be

```
ifelse(test, result1, ifelse(test2, result2, result3))
```

A key difference is that in the second example, `test`, `result1`, `result2` and `result3` are all vectors.

You should use the first if you want to do the *same* set of operations on your entire dataset, but *which* set depends on a test. The second is meant for vectorised calculations, where you want to carry out *different* operations on each element of a vector.

Comment: Just to complicate (or simplify!) matters, R's `if` is *also* a function. For example, you can write `x <- if(a < b) 1 else 2`, as opposed to `if(a < b) x <- 1 else x <- 2`. But that's tangential to the question.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I understand the question, but a natural R equivalent of your Excel code would be

```
if (a1 < 20)
  a1 * 1
else if (a1 < 50)
  a1 * 2
else if (a1 < 100)
  a1 * 3
else
  a1 * 4
```

And you could put curly braces around the `a1 * n` expressions if you wanted.  However, if `a1` is a vector rather than a scalar, you probably want to evaluate the comparisons in parallel for all vector elements, which is done with `ifelse`, which *does* nest like your Excel construct:

```
ifelse(a1 < 20, a1 * 1,
       ifelse(a1 < 50, a1 * 2,
              ifelse(a1 < 100, a1 * 3,
                               a1 * 4)))
```

A third way to write it, for vector `a1`, takes advantage of logical indexing:

```
a2 <- a1 # take a copy
a2[a1 >=  20 & a1 <  50] <- a1[a1 >=  20 & a1 <  50] * 2
a2[a1 >=  50 & a1 < 100] <- a1[a1 >=  50 & a1 < 100] * 3
a2[a1 >= 100           ] <- a1[a1 >= 100           ] * 4
```

Comment: I would interpret this, and tell me if I am wrong, please, that the `if`, `else`, `else`, `else` is the better way to go, rather than the `ifelse` approach.  The `ifelse` approach looks to be very nested, which as I explained (or tried to) in the question, are a pain to deal with.  Is one better than the other?  Thanks

Comment: Which one you want depends on the contents of `a1`.  If it is a scalar, yes, go with the `if`-`else if` chain which is easier to read.  If it is a *vector*, though, you may *need* `ifelse`'s element-by-element evaluation.  And I'll edit in a third way which is in some ways more R-idiomatic.

Comment: You are right, the third way is often called the "elegant R style", but if I tell this to my students, they laugh at me, and with reason. The fact that I have to make a copy first, and then repeat the same (did you check???) conditions on the left and on the right side is an example of bad style in the non-R programmer's world. Some attempts have been made with dataframes (transform, plyr) but in general I believe this is ugly. Duck and run.

Answer (score 6):

Many new users of R are confused about `if`. It evaluates only a single value and then executes either the expression that follows or the `else` clause. In R the `ifelse` function is generally what former SAS, Excel, and SPSS users are going to want and it will support nesting. There is the `switch` function that might be helpful in some instances, although I do not see how your set of non-exclusive logical conditions would immediately fit into its logic.

In your case, I would think instead about using the findInterval function. This would accomplish the combined operations of logical and mathematical operation in your example (and would return a vector if "A" were a vector) :

```
A*( 1+ findInterval( A, c(20,50,100) )  )  # OR 
A*( 1+ findInterval( A, c(-Inf, 20, 50, 100) )  ) # the equivalent using -Inf
```

And thinking about it a bit further The `findInterval` function could also be used as the first argument to `switch` if you wanted a function to be applied to "A".

(Further comment: I was assuming that your "A1" expression would get copied down a column  or row of cellls in an Excel spreadsheet and would in the process have the row or column references incremented in the particular automagical manner that Excel supports becoming A2, A3, etc. That is a different programing perspective than any of the more general languages you are comparing to. Operations on R vectors are analogous but would not generally need the "1", "2", "3" ... entries and so I omitted them from the code.)

Comment: It is very handy. Can be used similarly as with `match` as an indexing strategy. The other vectorized approach would be to use `cut` but that gets pretty messy.